# Style embedded Instagram Photos horizontally

Tags: css, instagram, embed

I am having a hard time adding a simple style to embedded instagram photos. I wanted the photos side by side so I used an unordered list and styled it so it was not bulleted and listed them horizontally. However, the style just does not seem to be applied to the embedded Instagram photos.

The CSS

```
#instapost ul
{
list-style-type: none;
}

#instapost ul li { 
display: inline;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="instapost">
<ul>
    <li>(copy any post from instagram and make max-width=320)</li>
    <li>(copy any post from instagram and make max-width=320)</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The full example with embedded Instagram photos can be seen here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/edwardgam/0k7smgvk/4/

(I am actually using WordPress and a WordPress plugin 'Simple Instagram Embed' so I just copy the URL of the Instagram photo (instead of the Instagram provided embed code) and paste into the appropriate place in my Wordpress post. However, this problem exists whether I use the plugin or not).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#instapost ul li { 
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. That actually works really well. But I failed to mentioned that there other elements after this and it appears to have messed the the format of the other items.  What I did was add a new  css 

`#instapost-clear {
` clear: left;
`}

Then called it after each div i.e. 
`<div id='instapost-clear></div> 

It seemed to have worked but calling the div seems awkward and I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. I have updated the jsfiddle in any case. 
 Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I could not edit the comment in time to fix the code display issues.