# Embedding Instagram posts with data-instgrm-version="8" in Wordpress; custom CSS no longer works

Tags: css, instagram, embed

I had previously asked a question on how to embed Instagram (IG) posts side by side with a max width of 320px here -> [Style embedded Instagram Photos horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247728/style-embedded-instagram-photos-horizontally). Thanks to another developer here on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8190022/ryan-parrish), I received a solution that worked perfectly until Instagram changed their embed code (now data-instgrm-version="8"). Here is the custom CSS that previously worked:

```
#instapost ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
}

#instapost ul li { 
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#instapost-clear {
 clear: left;
}
```

However, version 8 of the embedded code does not seem to work as well with this CSS. It does not seem to render some of the Instagram posts within the 320px max width. It is hard to describe what is happening but I created this page on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/edwardgam/hz4159uz/3/
to show the html with the embedded IG code, the CSS, and the resulting rendered page (Note: the reason I wanted 2 posts on the same line is so that I would choose 2 posts from the same Instagram account, and the next line would be a different account).

There are a few seconds before the images appear where the format seems like it may be correct but once the photos start to appear, some of them no longer fit within their containers and start to run into each other.

Thank you for reading all this!

Answer (score 0):

Although nothing has changed, the css seems to work now. Not sure if Instagram realized that the embed code was broken or if something was wrong with my computer. The CSS appears to work again.